# Comb. measures in pbi displays

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to make a visual(stacked bar chart) where I show both the different totals for each category, but I also want the year on year sale in %. So that each bar shows 2 measures, one that is the total and one that is the YOY sale. I cant put 2 measures in the value column.. Do you have any tips?

Comment: You can create an additional table, where you add a column for category: sales/ YOY/etc each category would be a separate bar in stacked bar chart;

Comment: Not really sure what you mean?... Do you mind explaining a bit more?